# font-feature-settings : 'tnum' , 'lnum' : Not Working

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-feature-settings

I am trying to use `font-feature-settings: 'tnum' on, 'lnum' on;` style on a custom font, but I am unable to see any visible effect of this property on the font.

Moreover, [in my JSFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhapisero/dzvbcnjw/6/#&togetherjs=mz6cht5Idg), I am getting css compile error

> "Expected no more than 1 declaration"

1. Is this css font-feature-property correct?
2. Is there any specific css property which is needed for this to take effect?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add "on"; just list the features.

`font-feature-settings: 'tnum', 'lnum'`

See the [CSS Fonts Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#font-feature-settings-prop) for details and examples.

Comment: Hi Peter,
Thanks for responding quickly :)
I tried your suggestion but I am not able to see any difference in JSFiddle. Haven't gone through CSS Fonts Module, will go through it later.